# Hibernet with java ArrayList

Tags: java, hibernate, serialization

i'm try to persist object (PERSON) with ArrayList but i get this execption:

```
ERROR:2012-04-23 20:58:54,336 org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor  - IllegalArgumentException in class: Entities.Person, setter method of property: msgList
ERROR:2012-04-23 20:58:54,336 org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor  - expected type: java.util.ArrayList, actual value: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList
```

Person class:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long id;
    private String _email;
    private ArrayList<AnsMsg> msgList=new ArrayList<AnsMsg>();

     long getId() {
        return id;
    }
  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
  public String getEmail() {
    return _email;
}


public void set_email(String _email) {
    this._email = _email;
}

public ArrayList<AnsMsg> getMsgList() {

   return msgList;
}


public void setMsgList(ArrayList<AnsMsg> msgList) {
    this.msgList = msgList;
}
}
```

Person Hbm:

```
    <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Entities.Person" table="PERSON">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="increment" />
        </id>
        <property name="_email" type="java.lang.String" access="field">
            <column name="_EMAIL" />
        </property>

     <list name="msgList" cascade="all"  >
           <key column="parent_id"/>
             <index column="idx" />
            <one-to-many class="msg.AnsMsg" />
        </list>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

now i don't want to use `List` instead `ArrayList`

```
(private List<AnsMsg> msgList=new ArrayList<AnsMsg>();)
```

because when i get person from DB Hibernate return `org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList` and i need to Serialize and Deserialize this object (Java server and android app) and "org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList" is't implements Serializable (or i'm wrong because i get null object when i try to Deserialize in android side).

this is my Deserialize/Serialize method:

```
 public static byte[] serializeObject(Object o) { 
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 

            try { 
              ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos); 
              out.writeObject(o); 
              out.close(); 


              byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray(); 

              return buf; 
            } 
            catch(IOException ioe)
            { 


              return null; 
            }
              catch(Exception e)
                {


                return null;
                }

          } 

 public static Object deserializeObject(byte[] b) {



Object object=null;
          try { 


ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new       ByteArrayInputStream(b)); 
               object = in.readObject(); 
              in.close(); 

              return object; 
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) { 


          return null; 
        } catch(IOException ioe) { 


          return null; 
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        String ex=e.toString();
        return object; 
        }
      }
```

**Update:**

when i try to use List instead ArrayList

when i try do Deserialize this object in the android side 
(with "deserializeObject" method ) when i get to

```
object = in.readObject();
```

line it's throw

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList.
```

this way i try to use ArrayList.

how can i map this array list?
or there is a batter way to work with Hibernate in this case?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

You are using the  `ArrayList` which is the implementation of List interface and hibernate is returning [PersistentList](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/collection/PersistentList.html) which is also the implementation of List interface. So you should not be specific to ArrayList change Your ArrayList to java.util.List so it can accept any implementation of java.util.List . It will also solves your issue.

Comment: i know it, but the problem is when i try do Deserialize this object in the android side (with "deserializeObject" method ) when i get to object = in.readObject(); line it's throw  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentList. this way i try to use arrayLIST

Answer (score 1):

your types in your POJO method signatures are still ArrayList, you need to change it to List everywhere

Answer (score 1):

IMHO You are going the wrong way.
These are options you have:

- Copy the entities to POJOs and send them to android device. (Ineffective)
- Add hibernate as library to your android app. This is too much for the android. (Bloats your android app)
- Use different means of serialization (JSON, XML)

I would use different means of serialization - JSON. There are libraries that make the process quite painless.